# Email DB back up file automatically with SQL Server email management tool?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, email

I have successfully configured SQL Server Email Management to send emails but i wonder to know if there is a way to send database backup files with this on specific time on every day automatically ?
I tried to read some forums about this but all forums including Stack overflow is talking to send email with SQL Server but i did not find any single topic on my question.
If this possible or i need to email backup of database files via coding ?

Comment: Are you sure you want to send database via email? What's the size of the DB? There're better ways to get backups offsite.

Comment: DB files are above 10MB each , please tell me if there are better ways ? or if i need to complete this job by through webservices?

Comment: it could be as simple as creating a Windows Scheduler task. It can run a batch file with an "xcopy" command to copy BAK files to another local server or a command line FTP tool to send file to a remote server. If this is really critical data - you can subscribe to a commercial (not free) service that takes backups of the DB via agents and hosts copies on their owns servers

Comment: @YuriyGalanter can you please send me a useful link of this ?